# How to read byte type string from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file. And this file's content is a byte type, like this

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />\r\n<!--<META http-equiv=Page-Enter content=blendTrans(Duration=0.5)>\r\n<META http-equiv=Page-Exit content=blendTrans(Duration=0.5)> -->\r\n<title>\xba...'
```

How can I translate it into

```
value = b'...'  # txt file content
```

Comment: You can't fix the code that created the file in the first place? Something wrote `str(bytesobject)` to a file instead of opening it in binary mode.

Comment: is this your exact file content (including backquotes and `b'`) or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate the bytes literal:

```
bytesobject = ast.literal_eval(filecontents)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import ast
>>> foo = "b'bytes value as a literal'"
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
>>> ast.literal_eval(foo)
b'bytes value as a literal'
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(foo))
<class 'bytes'>
```

However, it would be much better if you could just fix the source of the error, which is the code that created that file in the first place. Presumably that code used `str()` on a bytes value to write the data to a text file, where it should instead have opened a file in binary mode.